# Wordpress RSS2 href attribute in <a> tags inside feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, href, feed, rss2

I'm new to wordpress, in my feed (rss2) i've noticed that links are displayed like this:

```
<a title="myTitle" href="" target="_blank">my text</a>
```

As you can see the href attribute is empty because the rss2 function

get_the_content_feed with the filter "rss2" probably cut off href attribute.

Is it possible to retrieve href attribute?

Example of what I want

```
  <a title="myTitle" href="http://www.mylink.com" target="_blank">my text</a>
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I post this in case someone needs, I solved this problem, it was a plugin called RSS Image Feed (https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-image-feed/) that conflicted with ancor tags.

Disable it and it works again.

Cheers